# I am afraid I have got no money

Tags: past-participles

I am just wondering that sentence mean present tense.

> I am afraid I have got no money.

If it is a present tense, why that writer use "have got"?

Comment: _Have got_ is just an informal way of saying _have_. It has been much discussed on this forum, for example https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/126072/have-and-have-got-in-bre

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I've got, I have](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/78735/ive-got-i-have)